# Aggregate data with given bins by dates in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

I have two dataframes, one is the score with a given date,

```
date   score
2022-12-01   0.28
2022-12-01   0.12
2022-12-01   0.36
2022-12-01   0.42
2022-12-01   0.33
2022-12-02   0.15
2022-12-03   0.23
2022-12-03   0.25
```

Another dateframe is score bins,

```
breakpoints
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
```

The breakpoint `0.1` means any values less or equals to 0.1.
How do I create a dataframe that group the data with this known bins by date? I tried to use `numpy.histogram` which the aggregate function works good but doesn't know how to group it by date.
My expected output will be like,

```
breakpoints   2022-12-01   2022-12-02   2022-12-03   ...
0.1            0            0            0
0.2            1            1            0
0.3            1            0            2
0.4            2            0            0
...           ...          ...          ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**step1)**  Create a new column for the steps:

```
import numpy as np
df['steps'] = np.round(np.floor((df.score)/0.1)*0.1, 1)
```

**step2)** Do the group by and rename the aggregate column:

```
out_df = (df[['date', 'steps']]).groupby(['date', 'steps']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
```

**step3)** use the pivot function and replace the None values:

```
out_df = out_df.pivot(index='steps', columns='date', values='count').reset_index().fillna(0)
```

the final result  looks like this:

[image]